# Matrix whose elements are tensors.

Tags: tensors

If I have a 2×2 matrix whose nonzero elements are 2 order covariante tensor, then is the determinant a 2 order tensor with the same type of covariance?
Please excuse my ignorance of this doubt that I do not even know if it makes sense.

Thank you in advance!